# Number of ordered pairs with a constant sum?

Tags: combinatorics

I have been struggling with the question: how many n-tuples of nonnegative integers have sum k? (How many ordered tuples $(a_1,a_2,...,a_n)$ exist such that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i = k$?) I have thought about using generator functions, but I can't make it work. It seems a lot like the partition problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any pair of natural numbers $n$ and $k$, the number of distinct $n$-tuples of non-negative integers whose sum is $k$ is given by the binomial coefficient
$$
{n+k-1\choose k}
$$
(see [stars and bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29)).